# CARD-ACTION-STATUS response header fails to parse in Microsoft Teams Private Channels

Tags: http-post, webhooks, microsoft-teams, actionable-notification

When we send a MessageCard to a Microsoft Teams channel via an "Incoming Webhook" connector, when that card contains an HttpPOST potentialAction and the target of the POST returns a CARD-ACTION-STATUS header in the reply, on public channels the content of that header is displayed as a new message.  However, if the same MessageCard is sent to a private channel the CARD-ACTION-STATUS header fails to parse and the error message "There was a problem submitting your changes.  Try again in a minute" appears.

This worked perfectly fine until around Dec 8th, 2020.   I have also verified that the target of the HttpPOST did receive the request and did reply with the CARD-ACTION-STATUS header for both public and private channels.

This is the message card I posted to the Teams channel via an Incoming Webhook Connector :

```
{
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "@context": "https://schema.org/extensions",
    "expectedActors": [],
    "themeColor": "993399",
    "hideOriginalBody": true,
    "title": "Simple Teams MessageCard",
    "text": "Card Action Status",
    "potentialAction": [
        {
            "@type": "HttpPOST",
            "name": "Test HttpPOST",
            "target": "https://mydummyapi.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sandbox/teams",
            "bodyContentType": "application/json",
            "body": "{'message': 'Anybody There'}"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the result from a public channel :
[public channel result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiWPU.png)

This is the result from a private channel :
[private channel result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IFHe.png)

One last thing of note.  The response header "CARD-UPDATE-IN-BODY" works on both private and public channels when you pass a new message card in the body of the response.  So it is only with the "CARD-ACTION-STATUS" header, and only in private channels.

Comment: Hi @GuyWaguespack, we are checking on this internally and will update on this as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you.  Look forward to your findings.

Comment: We are not able to repro the issue at our end. When we use http post request we are receiving the http post to the target URL. Are you still facing the issue. could you please conform?

Comment: The bug isn't that the Http Post target doesn't receive the message, it is when it returns the "CARD-ACTION-STATUS" response header to a private channel, the message doesn't display.  There is a case opened for this (Case #:24403240) that identified the problem and a solution is due to be deployed by the end of March.

Comment: This appears to have been fixed now.  Thanks MSFT.

Comment: I have confirmed that this was fixed by Microsoft at the end of March, 2021. Case #:24403240

Answer (score 0):

**For better visibility coping answer from @nikitha comments**

We are not able to repro the issue at our end. When we use http post request we are receiving the http post to the target URL.

Comment: The bug isn't that the Http Post target doesn't receive the message, it is when it returns the "CARD-ACTION-STATUS" response header to a private channel, the message doesn't display. There is a case opened for this (Case #:24403240) that identified the problem and a solution is due to be deployed by the end of March.